# Upgrading the Couchbase Java SDK from 3.0.9 to 3.1.2 creating the issue (DocumentExistsException: Document with the given id already exists)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: com.couchbase.client.core.error.DocumentExistsException: Document with the given id already exists
java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:314)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:319)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:645)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)\n\tat com.couchbase.client.core.msg.BaseRequest.succeed(BaseRequest.java:143)\n\tat com.couchbase.client.core.io.netty.kv.KeyValueMessageHandler.decodeAndComplete(KeyValueMessageHandler.java:322)\n\tat com.couchbase.client.core.io.netty.kv.KeyValueMessageHandler.decode(KeyValueMessageHandler.java:301)\n\tat com.couchbase.client.core.io.netty.kv.KeyValueMessageHandler.channelRead(KeyValueMessageHandler.java:228)\n\tat com.couchbase.client.core.deps.io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)

1 common frames omitted\nCaused by: com.couchbase.client.core.error.DocumentExistsException: Document with the given id already exists\n\tat com.couchbase.client.java.kv.InsertAccessor.lambda$insert$0(InsertAccessor.java:45)\n\tat java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642)\n\t... 33 common frames omitted\n\n"}